# Node NPM Glob -

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have a problem with installing Glob with NPM.
I searched for about an 1hour in the internet for an solution but didnÄt find one.
I hope you guys can help me.

1. I use: "npm i glob"
2. I get this:

````
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'globe@0.3.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.2', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 42 packages in 965ms

3 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run npm audit for details. ```
````

I don't know what's wrong there. I hope you can help me.
~Kitty Cat Craft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to install [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) (as you wrote in step 1), then you probably had a typo in your command as the error message is about the package [globe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globe) (with a 'e' in the end).

The error occurs because 'globe' set an explicit required node version of 0.8. in their [package.json](https://github.com/makesites/globe/blob/master/package.json#L13), however you have version 16.13.2 installed. If you are actually trying to install 'globe' I recommend against it as it seems really outdated (and you'd have to use the unsupported, super old node version).